# How do I test an ISO file?

Tags: configuration, 19.04

I have an iso file for ubuntu 19.04 and a SHA256SUM file. How do I run the iso test?

Comment: Run `sha256sum ubuntu.iso`.

Comment: https://help.ubuntu.com/community/HowToMD5SUM